# How to use destructor with inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, destructor

Let's say I have objects: B Ob1, C Ob2. I want to build a destructor for classes B and C, but I'm not sure how to destroy B.bb and C.cc and how to acces them. Also, is there a way I am able to do this without making classes friends of class A?

```
class A
{
protected:
   int a, aa;
public:
   A();
   A(int a, int aa);
   ~A();
   friend class B;
   friend class C;
};
class B
{
protected:
   int b;
   A bb;
public:
   B();
   A(int b, A bb);
   ~B();
};
class C: class B
{
private:
   int c;
   A cc;
public:
   C();
   C(int c, A cc);
   ~C();
  };
```

Comment: No friends are necessary, and neither are non-default destructors. The classes are too simple to need to worry about this right now.

Comment: You can however _not_ make a constructor for `A` in `B` like you now do.

Comment: Handy reading: [The Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 4):

You don't. They are destroyed automatically. `friend`s are not needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use inheritance, the destructor should be virtual:

```
class B
{
    ...
public:
   B();
   A(int b, A bb);
   virtual ~B();
};
```

The rationale, is that as soon as you will use polymorphism and pointers bad things could happen:

```
B *obj = new C();
...
delete obj;       // if ~B is not virtual, you never call C destructor...
```

Comment: "_As soon as you use inheritance_" ... that's a little over-simplified. If you don't plan to destroy objects through base class pointers, you don't need a virtual base class destructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Of course you are right.  For that reason, I said *should* and not *must*. But without knowing the full usage context, I would advise a C++ beginner to follow that rule because it is simple. It may not lead to the most efficient code, but at least it should be harmless, unless you need special properties like POD classes.

Comment: Got it - It could be worth mentioning in the answer why you suggest making them virtual. You'd get my vote :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I tried to be lazy. Happily you were here :-)

Comment: Happy to be of service :-)